# Must wizards have to register for the draft/serve in muggle military?

Tags: harry-potter

In the US, men 18-25 have register for Selective Services, and in other countries there is mandatory military service.  Are wizards exempt from registering for the draft/doing mandatory service?

Comment: In the UK there is no mandatory military service.

Comment: @Valorum Not now, but according to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_United_Kingdom, there would have been one during one of the earlier wizarding wars.

Comment: The books are set in the UK, and they don't have mandatory military service. We unfortunately know very little about the US wizards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wizards are known to fight in Muggle wars...

From the  Pottermore *[History of Magic in North America: The 1920s](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en)*

> The wizards of America had played their part in the Great War of 1914-1918, even if the overwhelming majority of their No-Maj compatriots were ignorant of their contribution. As there were magical factions on both sides, their efforts were not decisive, but they won many victories in preventing additional loss of life, and in defeating their magical enemies.

Considering there was a draft for the Great War (aka World War I) and wizards did fight, we make the conclusion that some were drafted.

Comment: Sounds (to me) as though they were used in a special way, not just leave your wand at home and hide amongst everyone else. Interesting. Maybe not safe to assume they were conscripted, but maybe.

Comment: @ThruGog Yeah, not really sure how many were "boots on the ground" types, for a society that rejects modern technology it may be hard to pass basic training (e.g. learn how to use a rifle). Perhaps there were a great number of wizard medics...

Comment: I was envisioning wizard task forces!

Comment: @ThruGog Maybe, if they were being given order by a wizard CO to take on enemy wizard groups. I think if they were in an actual army this could not be the case as it is mentioned the No-Majs/Muggles were unaware of their contributions and if they broke off into their own task force would have declared AWOL or deserters.

Comment: Perhaps the Ministry enrolled some wizards, trained them, formed teams or similar and set them out to help the war effort in specific ways. Almost like spies or similar. And, in the UK case we know the Prime Minister knew about magic, so maybe he just knew 'The Ministry of Magic is doing what they can.'